# zend framework 2 loading modules in other module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have two modules  called 'image manager' and 'add products'. I want to include all image manager view inside a div in products module .

someone please help me,

Regards,

Lanka

Comment: could you take a look at my answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your comments, i see that it is not a ZF2 error, and probably not even a third party module, so it could be an ElFinder Error. Probably it cannot find some required resources.

Reading some code and some webdites, i think that probably you are just lacking the url option of the viewhelper, so ElFinder can find the backend route he tries to connect to.

With the QuElFinder, the route to the connector is  `/quelfinder/connector`
 so in your view, the code will be:

```
echo $this->QuElFinder('elfinder', array(
    'width' => "50%",
    'height' => '300',
    'url' => '/quelfinder/connector'
    )
);
```

Also, you should go to `QuElFinder/config/module.config.php` and check everything under

```
 'QuConfig'=>array(
        'QuElFinder'=>array(
```

because as you can see in the QuElFinder controller, in the `connectorAction()` function, it is reading that configuration, and there is a lot of paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a controller action from within another controller action using the `forward()` plugin, where you can then add the response (`ViewModel`) as a child view.

The main benefit of this is that you reuse and keep the controller logic encapsulated for each 'view'. This allows the build up a widget like views without coupling/duplicating code.

For example

```
class ProductsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function viewProductAction()
    {
      //... View product controller logic
      //
      //

      $view = new ViewModel(array('foo', 'bar'));

      // Dispatch the controller to view images for this 'product_id'
      $viewManagerView = $this->forward()->dispatch('ImageManager\Controller\ViewImageController', array(
        'action'     => 'view-images',
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
      ));
      // Attach the child view to the main view
      if ($viewManagerView instanceof ViewModel) {
        $view->addChild($viewManagerView, 'productImages');
      }

      return $view;
    }
```

}

An then within a `products-module/products/view-product.phtml` render the child view

```
echo $this->productImages;
```

You can read more about the forward plugin [in the documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-forward)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of scenario sounds typical for a [`ViewHelper`](http://blog.evan.pro/creating-a-simple-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2). Though it requires application logic, too. You'd need to have some way of gluing `Products` and `Images` together.

Since it's two separate Modules you'd probably extend the `ProductForm` and inject a new Element into the Form so that the User could choose the images he want to glue to the Product. This would usually be a 1-N Relationship since one Product can have many Images but one Image should only belong to one Product.

If you need more help than that, then you need to start coding and come back with real questions :)

Comment: I'm using zend framework 2 with elfinder and it's working fine (inside elfinder view).
I have module named options , the problem is when i'm using that elfinder helper inside options view it gave me error called "Unable to connect to backend. Backend not found."
this is the code i'm using inside options view 
echo
$this->QuElFinder(
'elfinder',
array(
'width' => "50%",
'height' => "300",
));
Please someone help me,
Thanks
Lanka

Comment: @pandukhabaya I have no clue about elFinder, all I know is that people have lots of problems with it. Just ask the elFinder Team/Guy on GitHub

Comment: i guess you are using the  QuElFinder module from Celtico, right? that error message is not anywhere in the code of QuElFinder, you should follow the code to see where it is crashing. Probaly is something with ElFinder, or with QuElFinder, or with your code